# HTTP response in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, http, httpresponse

I know HTTP extension is depracated in PHP 5.3 onwords. So is their any way to make a HTTP response.
This is my php code in php 5.2. How to make it suitable for php 5.4.

```
//process the request by fetching the info
$headers = http_get_request_headers();
$result = http_get_request_body();
//do stuff with the $headers and $result variables....
//then send your response
HttpResponse::status(200);
HttpResponse::setContentType('text/xml');
HttpResponse::setHeader('From', 'ABCD');
HttpResponse::setData($sq_data);
HttpResponse::send();
```

Comment: What does "suitable" mean? Undeprecate the extension? Hide some E_DEPRECATED messages?

Comment: Also, what extension do you mean exactly? The [PECL one](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) says nothing about deprecation.

Comment: how to Undeprecate http in php5.4 ? sutiable means to make http reaponse function in php5.4 ?? is their any other way to perform http response ??

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the class is deprecated? I don't see anything about that anywhere.

Comment: You could just replace all that with simple `header` calls and an echo/print of your response body …

Comment: in further version of php http extension is not avalable. iam using wamp server.

Comment: Have you *installed* the PECL HTTP extension on those newer versions...?

Comment: how to do http response using 'header' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is based on a misunderstanding:

> "in further version of php http extension is not available. iam using wamp server."

The PECL HTTP extension is [perfectly available for any current PHP version](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http), it's simply *not installed by default* and must be [installed](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http) as a [PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php). In the best case that's as simple as this typed on the command line:

```
$ pecl install pecl_http
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I was searching pecl for 5.3 and got for 5.4 so upgraded php to 5.4 thus it’s working for me.